block certain urls on my VPN server using iptables
I have a private VPN server.  Users have multiple ways to connect to my server: wireguard, shadowsocks.
I want to restrict my users from accessing some sites.
As I understand, the most common way - is to use iptables. I fail to write a rule even to block a single IP address.

Do I correctly understand, that I need to add rules to table=FILTER & chain=FORWARD?

Why does this has no influence when I ping from a client terminal?
iptables -A FORWARD -d 5.255.255.242 -j DROP    enter code here

What can you recomend to ban sites by URL? My idea is to periodically run script to resolve my unwanted sites and generate new rules for them.


